# php - Syntax working on localhost, not working on godaddy server

Tags: php, cakephp, dompdf

I am trying to create pdf file with css.

Here is my code-which is working fine on localhost

```
       require_once(VENDORS . DS .'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');     
       $dompdf = new DOMPDF();          
       $html = '<html>
       <head><style>body{
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;';
```

But on server it gives me error.

> Error: syntax error, unexpected 'px' (T_STRING).

Comment: Try the [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string declaration in case it's a mixup with the newlines being different.

Comment: We will need some extra information such as `PHP Version`, `php.ini differences` and `apache version`

Comment: Is that the entirety of the code? And do you have a line number that correlates with the sample (i.e. which line is causing the error)?